# Associated model validations in Rails - and some questions of design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a Task which has many LoggedTimes. I want to put a limit of 8 hours of logged time against a task on any given day. What is the best way to go about this so that I can check whether the person's latest logged time "takes their total over the limit" for a day, so to speak?

Here's where I am beginning (Task.rb):

```
validate :max_logged_daily_time

def max_logged_daily_time
    if (params[:session_time] + (logged_times.where(:created_at => Date.today).to_a.sum(&:session_time)/60)) > 8
      errors.add_to_base("Can't have more than 8 hours logged a day") 
      logged_time.errors.add('session_time', 'Logged times exceeded today')
    end
  end
```

Currently this validation is not working (adding another LoggedTime once 8 hours of previous logged times have been registered simply adds it to the rest, instead of throwing an error. Since no errors are being thrown, I'm struggling to pick my way through the problem. Is it something to do with the handling of params?

Which brings me to the question of design: in theory I could revise the view so that the user is only able to submit 8 hours minus the total amount of time they've logged that day; however this seems like a clunky solution and against the principle of keeping validations in the model. (And it certainly doesn't help me solve this model validations problem).

Any advice here?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logged_times

  def hours_today
    LoggedTime.daily_hours_by_task(self).to_a.sum(&:session_time)
  end

end

class LoggedTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task

  scope :daily_hours_by_task, lambda { |task| task.\
    logged_times.\
    where('logged_times.created_at >= ? AND logged_times.created_at < ?',
          Date.today, Date.today + 1) }

  validate :max_logged_daily_time

  private

  def max_logged_daily_time
    if task && ((task.hours_today + session_time) / 60.0) > 8
      errors.add('session_time', 'Logged times exceeded today')
    end
  end

end
```

Some notes:

- `created_at` is a DateTime, so you'll
  need to test both the start and end
  of the day
- The validation also prevents the
  addition of a single LoggedTime which by itself exceeds the maximum.
- Dividing by an integer truncates and
  will give the wrong result -- add the
  `.0` to convert to a float.
- This only validates the LoggedTime,
  not the Task, so you might want to
  add `validates_associated` in the
  Task model.
- Validation is bypassed when Task is nil

**EDIT**

Well, `hours_today` should really be called `minutes_today`, but you get the idea.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Some of the concepts here are newer to me (noob) so I'll have to pick through them and digest and see if they work :) cheers

Comment: Hi again zetetic. may I just ask why I wouldn't validate via the Task model, and bypass the validates_associated? In other words what is the virtue of your scope method on LoggedTime compared to validating in the Task model?                                     def total_hrs_for_date(date = Date.today)
    practices.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', date, date+1).to_a.sum(&:session_time)/60.0
  end
  
  def hours_today
      Practice.daily_hours_by_activity(self).to_a.sum(&:session_time)
  end

Comment: You can use backticks(`) for a monospaced font in comments, but that's all the formatting you get.

Comment: Re: where to put the validation, IMO it works better in LoggedTime because that way you could add a Task without any hours. That was an assumption on my part -- maybe you see if differently. You could try moving it to the Task and see how it works. BTW it's easier to write the scope on the `belongs_to` side, so that's where I put it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a separate method for getting the sum of hours for a given day.

```
def total_hrs_logged_for_date(date)
  #some code
end
```

Test that method to make sure it works.

Possibly also do the same for calculating the current logged time.

then use those those two in your custom validator

so this line

```
if (params[:session_time] + (logged_times.where(:created_at => Date.today).to_a.sum(&:session_time)/60)) > 8
```

becomes

```
if total_hrs_logged_for_date(Date.today) + current_time_being_logged > 8
```

At the very least it will help you narrow down which of these isn't working.

I also notice that you have "params[:session_time]"

I think this is in Task.rb which sounds like a model.  Probably what you want is just "session_time" instead.

Comment: thanks for the advice. just wondering though whether I will be able to call session_time as that's a method on LoggedTime... Since that is not yet saved (as it's not yet validated), how would I access that data from the view?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up revising Zetetic's response slightly, because I couldn't get it to work as is.

In the end, this worked:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :logged_times
  validates_associated :logged_times

  def minutes_today
    logged_times.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at < ?', Date.today, Date.today + 1)
  end

end
```

and the LoggedTime model:

```
class LoggedTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task

  validate :max_logged_daily_time

  private

  def max_logged_daily_time
    if task && ((task.minutes_today + session_time) / 60.0) > 8
      errors.add('session_time', 'Logged times exceeded today')
    end
  end

end
```

I'm not sure why the scope method baulked, but it did. Any hints Zetetic?